# Background shorthand for background-size and height and width

Tags: css

Is there a shorthand to incorporate the `height`, `width`, and `background-size` of the image all in the `background`?

I know you can do:

`background: url("") /*offset-x*/ /*offset-y*/`

but is there something like:

`background: url("") /*width*/ /*offset-x*/ /*height*/ /*offset-y*/`

I ask, because I'm trying to use [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RCHtK/) with a single image (a sprite), rather than a images for each section.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference (scroll down)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wvwea/1/

Comment: Well, that's the part I know, @TimMedora. The part I'm having trouble with is "cropping" that image with CSS as well.

Comment: Okay, understood. You *can* set the height/width, but that will size the entire image (not crop it).